# Ubuntu 19.04 Alternate Keyboard Shortcut for Home/End Buttons

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, 19.04

I am using **Ubuntu 19.04** and what to create key combinations for **Home** and **End** buttons. I am unable to understand what should I enter in the command dialog?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**General answer on the "command" item**

In the "Command" section of the "Set Custom Shortcut" dialog, you need to provide a command that needs to be executed when the key combination is pressed. That could be the name of an executable, e.g. `gnome-terminal` would cause the keyboard combination to lauch a terminal window, or `firefox` would cause firefox to launch. That command may also be an executable script containing a range of commands. For example, I have a hotkey that (only) blanks my screen (without locking or anything else). The script is called `blankscreen` and resides in my bin folder in my home folder. The script is nothing else than a small text file, containing:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 0.3 &&  xset dpms force off
```

The script file is set to be executable (right-click the script file, "Permissions" tab). In the "Command" section, I would then fill out the full pathname of the script:

```
/home/$USER/bin/blankscreen
```

(where "$USER" is to be replaced by your real login.)

**Specific answer on creating extra <kbd>home</kbd> key**

*Easy approach using Settings - Keyboard*

For what you want to do, i.e, have an extra key combination for <kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>End</kbd> you may need to resort to a utility `xdotool`. It can simulate key presses. Install xdotool first:  it is not installed by default. To create an extra Home, fill out following code directly in the "command" field:

```
sh -c "sleep 0.4 ; xdotool key Home
```

*Deeper system approach*

You can redefine keys and key combinations with tools such as `sxhkd` or `xbindkeys`. This will provide a much more integrated, seamless solution but requires some more technical skills to set up.

Comment: Thank you. It works with `xdotool` but why do we need to make it `sleep` first?

Comment: Try if it works without. If not (reliably), add the sleep command back in. Problem is that your modifier keys need to be released by the time xdotool presses Home. If answer helped, then please accept the answer.

Comment: Can you guide further on how to use `sxhkd` or `xbindkeys`

Comment: Feel free to ask a new specific question if you try xbindkeys or sxhkd. For xdotool, you may try the --clearmodifiers flag: that may allow to reduce or eliminate the delay: "xdotool --clearmodifiers key Home"

Answer (score 0):

To use 'Home' and 'End' as commands for keyboard shortcuts, it is neccesary to install `xdotool` and then enter as the command in the `Set Custom Shortcuts` window as:

`xdotool key --clearmodifiers Home`
or
`xdotool key --clearmodifiers End`

Without including the `--clearmodifiers` part I found that it would jump to the start of the page rather than the start of the sentence. Another reply here suggested that it was neccesary to preface with `sh -c "sleep 0.4 ;` but I found this stopped it from working.