# How to change a keyboard shortcut on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I just installed Ubuntu and got a new PC. I'm trying to make `Alt + Right/Left` to move to the end/beginning of the line similarly to how currently my `Home/End` keys are working.

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452386/how-to-change-keyboard-shortcuts) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard) and tried to follow by clicking on `keyboard shortcuts` under `settings`
[image]

I cliked on the `+` to add a new shortcut since I didn't find the `home/end` shortcuts there
[image]

But when I tried adding the new combination nothing happened
[image]

Comment: the "command" section is something that could be executed in the command line.  i think what you need is answered here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1154796/ubuntu-19-04-alternate-keyboard-shortcut-for-home-end-buttons